# Is there a public calendar for key Ubuntu events?

Tags: community, calendar, events, schedule

I've been looking at the schedule for [Ubuntu Developer Week (11th to 15th of July)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDeveloperWeek), and started entering the schedule into my [Google calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=nqmsjjjle7d5c9iiafdesqmspo@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Etc/GMT) ([XML](https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/nqmsjjjle7d5c9iiafdesqmspo@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic), [iCal](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/nqmsjjjle7d5c9iiafdesqmspo@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics), [HTML](https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=nqmsjjjle7d5c9iiafdesqmspo@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Etc/GMT)). At this point, I thought to myself... maybe there's a public calendar that is updated with key Ubuntu events? So that has lead to my question.

*Is there a complete public calendar for key Ubuntu events?*

**N.B:** Events like Ubuntu Developer Summit, Ubuntu Developer Week, Ubuntu Global Jam, Releases, LTS End-Of-Life dates, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is the official calendar:

- http://ubuntu-news.org/calendars/fridge/

And here are [the instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fridge/Calendar). Note that some teams have their own team calendars as well, but generally speaking anything important is put on the fridge calendar.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, as it's only meeting times; but following on from that link lead to the LoCo and Classroom calendars - very useful! :P People can subscribe to the LoCo/Classroom calendars themselves, but I'm going to also add in Alpha/Beta release dates from here: http://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricReleaseSchedule Will also add in the iCal and XML links in the question, so people can use the calendar too; the invite email address to the calendar is nqmsjjjle7d5c9iiafdesqmspo@group.calendar.google.com (using the same instructions as you pointed out above)

Comment: @Alex Adding all all those would be very useful, thanks!

Comment: Anytime Jorge ^.^ Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :P